# Animating Oscillating Elements with CSS Rotate Property

Tags: html, css

I have been looking to create a similar effect to https://www.google.com/events/io/logistics *(the inspiration)* however the 4 elements are not rendering correctly, one element jumps over the next. I have tried several iterations of this with no avail. You can see in this Fiddle one side jumps over the next. I have changed the perspective to see this more clearly.

http://jsfiddle.net/368Rc/ (UPDATED:7/11)

```
<div style="height: 300px;margin-top:40px;">
<div class="cube-wrap">
    <div class="cube depth">
        <div class="back-pane">back</div>
        <div class="left-pane">left</div>
        <div class="right-pane">right</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
    /*************** ANIMATIONS ***************/
    @-webkit-keyframes spin {
        from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0); }
        to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg); }
    }

    @-ms-keyframes spin {
        from { ms-transform: rotateY(0); }
        to { ms-transform: rotateY(360deg); }
    }

    @keyframes spin {
        from { transform: rotateY(0); }
        to { transform: rotateY(360deg); }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes spin-vertical {
        from { -webkit-transform: rotateX(0); }
        to { -webkit-transform: rotateX(-360deg); }
    }

    @-ms-keyframes spin-vertical {
        from { ms-transform: rotateX(0); }
        to { ms-transform: rotateX(-360deg); }
    }

    @keyframes spin-vertical {
        from { transform: rotateX(0); }
        to { transform: rotateX(-360deg); }
    }


    /*************** STANDARD CUBE ***************/
    .cube-wrap {
        -webkit-perspective: 1800px;
        -webkit-perspective-origin: 0% 1000px;

        -moz-perspective: 1800px;
        -moz-perspective-origin: 0% 1000px;

        -ms-perspective: 1800px;
        -ms-perspective-origin: 0% 1000px;

        perspective: 1800px;
        perspective-origin: 0% 1000px;
    }

    .cube {
        position: relative;
        width: 152px;
        margin: 0 auto;

        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -webkit-animation: spin 20s infinite linear;

        -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -moz-animation: spin 20s infinite linear; 

        -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -ms-animation: spin 20s infinite linear; 

        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        animation: spin 20s infinite linear; 
    }

    .cube div {
        position: absolute;
        width: 152px;
        height: 202px;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px rgba(125,125,125,0.8);
        font-size: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 200px;
        color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        font-family: sans-serif;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    /*************** DEPTH CUBE ***************/
    .depth div.back-pane {

        background: url("http://doggydish.com/PROJECTS/balloon-green-l.svg");

        -webkit-transform: translateZ(10px) rotateY(90deg);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;

        -moz-transform: translateZ(10px) rotateY(90deg);
        -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;

        -ms-transform: translateZ(10px) rotateY(90deg);
        -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;

        transform: translateZ(10px) rotateY(90deg);
        transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;

        left:10px;
    }
    .depth div.right-pane {
        -webkit-transform:rotateY(0deg) translateX(0px);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 200% 0;

        -moz-transform:rotateY(0deg) translateX(0px);
        -moz-transform-origin: 50% 200% 0;

        -ms-transform:rotateY(0deg) translateX(0px);
        -ms-transform-origin: 50% 200% 0;

        transform:rotateY(0deg) translateX(0px);
        transform-origin: 50% 200% 0;


        background: url("http://doggydish.com/PROJECTS/balloon-blue-r.svg");
    }
    .depth div.left-pane {
        -webkit-transform:rotateY(0deg) translateX(0px);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0% 0;

        -moz-transform:rotateY(0deg) translateX(0px);
        -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0% 0;

        -ms-transform:rotateY(0deg) translateX(0px);
        -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0% 0;

        transform:rotateY(0deg) translateX(0px);
        transform-origin: 50% 0% 0;


        background: url("http://doggydish.com/PROJECTS/balloon-blue-l.svg");
    }

    .depth div.front-pane {

        background: url("http://doggydish.com/PROJECTS/balloon-green-r.svg");

        -webkit-transform: translateZ(100px);
        -moz-transform: translateZ(100px);
        -ms-transform: translateZ(100px);
        transform: translateZ(100px);


    }
```

Note: I'm testing on Firefox/Chrome, there may be issues on SAFARI.

Answer (score 1):

Currently chrome doesn't support standard properties of transform.

so you need to use prefix to support all your browsers, even in key-frames.

i have updated one of your key-frames, to show how it works, so fix other keyframes as you want.

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mbanandetoro6/GjwA8/1/)

```
.balloon-cage2 {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    left:400px;
}
.balloon-green-r {
    background: url("http://doggydish.com/PROJECTS/balloon-green-r.svg");
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    cursor: default;
    width: 152px;
    height: 202px;
    text-align: right;
     -webkit-animation: rotateyr 6s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: rotateyr 6s linear infinite;
    animation: rotateyr 6s linear infinite;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    background-color:#1abc9c;
}
.balloon-green-l {
    background: url(http://doggydish.com/PROJECTS/balloon-green-l.svg);
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    cursor: default;
    width: 152px;
    height: 202px;
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-animation: rotateyl 6s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: rotateyl 6s linear infinite;
    animation: rotateyl 6s linear infinite;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
}
.balloon-blue-l {
    background: url(http://doggydish.com/PROJECTS/balloon-blue-l.svg);
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    cursor: default;
    width: 152px;
    height: 202px;
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-animation: rotateyl2 6s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: rotateyl2 6s linear infinite;
    animation: rotateyl2 6s linear infinite;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
}
.balloon-blue-r {
    background: url(http://doggydish.com/PROJECTS/balloon-blue-r.svg);
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    cursor: default;
    width: 152px;
    height: 202px;
    text-align: right;
    -webkit-animation: rotateyr2 6s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: rotateyr2 6s linear infinite;
    animation: rotateyr2 6s linear infinite;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateyr {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0% 0;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0% 0;
    }
}
@keyframes rotateyr {
    0% {
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
        transform-origin: 50% 0% 0;
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotateY(360deg);
        transform-origin: 50% 0% 0;
    }
}
@keyframes rotateyr2 {
    0% {
        transform: rotateY(90deg);
        transform-origin: 50% 0 0;
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotateY(450deg);
        transform-origin: 50% 0% 0;
    }
}
@keyframes rotateyl {
    0% {
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
        transform-origin: 50% 0 0;
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotateY(360deg);
        transform-origin: 50% 0 0;
    }
}
@keyframes rotateyl2 {
    0% {
        transform: rotateY(90deg);
        transform-origin: 50% 0 0;
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotateY(450deg);
        transform-origin: 50% 0 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have updated my comment. I also noticed the SVG image was not loading properly from my server, this has also been updated. Any additional ideas?

Comment: @JosephLake ya, one more thing, you need to use css perspective to show animation in 3d,this applies on parent element in your case its `.balloon-cage2`.

Comment: It seems this perspective did nothing more than distort the image. If you see my Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/g59jg/ you will see it rotates 180 degrees then it appears to rotate backwards another 180 degrees. I don't wish it to oscillate - but actually rotate 360 continuously. Any ideas?

Comment: @JosephLake i haven't found `perspective` used in demo, and even image is not loading, so i cant figure out the issue, please make the working demo, if jsfiddle is not showing your images then try another site.

Comment: You will see perspective now, I'm using a completely different approach. This will look slightly different - you will see the GREEN jumps over the BLUE, and visa versa. http://jsfiddle.net/368Rc/ (Please refresh your image cache on DoggyDish.com). I have intentionally removed one pane for example.

Comment: @JosephLake i think the flashing of side when rotating on top of each other is a bug, what you say?